# Hello guys, ask a question about the address of C++

Tags: c++

Why are mySwap02 and mySwap03 addresses different?

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

//1. Passing Directly
void mySwap01(int a, int b) {
    cout << "mySwap01's address a:" << &a << endl;
    cout << "mySwap01's address b:" << &b << endl;
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

//2. Passing by Pointer
void mySwap02(int* a, int* b) {
    cout << "mySwap02's address a:" << &a << endl;
    cout << "mySwap02's address b:" << &b << endl;
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;

}

//3. Passing by Reference
void mySwap03(int& a, int& b) {
    cout << "mySwap03's address a:" << &a << endl;
    cout << "mySwap03's address b:" << &b << endl;
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main() {

    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;

    // Memory address
    cout << "Memory address a:" << &a << endl; 
    cout << "Memory address b:" << &b << endl;

    mySwap01(a, b);
    cout << "a:" << a << " b:" << b << endl;

    mySwap02(&a, &b);
    cout << "a:" << a << " b:" << b << endl;

    mySwap03(a, b);
    cout << "a:" << a << " b:" << b << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

```
Memory Address a:000000220E3BFA5C
Memory Address b:000000220E3BFA58

mySwap01's address a:000000220E3BFA18
mySwap01's address b:000000220E3BFA1C
a:10 b:20

mySwap02's address a:000000220E3BFA10
mySwap02's address b:000000220E3BFA18
a:20 b:10

mySwap03's address a:000000220E3BFA5C
mySwap03's address b:000000220E3BFA58
a:10 b:20
```

Comment: What do you want to say?

Comment: Why do you expect them to be same (or different)? Where does that expectation come from?

Comment: Should I go ahead and translate this as an edit? Or should I flag this?

Comment: @RyanZhang I think translation would be better.

Comment: @RyanZhang Go ahead and do so.

Comment: In `mySwap02` you are printing the addresses of the *pointers* (the locations where pointers to `a` and `b` are stored), not the addresses of `a` and `b`.

Comment: So basically you could print the pointer, pointer, pointer address that you are pointing to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at what `mySwap03` is doing. Note that I've translated some of the Chinese here; I've submitted the edits, but they have yet to be approved, at least for now. (Edit: My edits have been approved.)

```
void mySwap03(int& a, int& b) {
    cout << "mySwap03's address a:" << &a << endl;
    cout << "mySwap03's address b:" << &b << endl;
...
```

Here, you pass `a` and `b` by reference. Then, you use `&` to take the address of `a` and `b`. As you are passing by reference, this address will be the same as the address of the temporary variables you created in `int main()`.

Now, let's look at `mySwap02`.

```
void mySwap02(int* a, int* b) {
    cout << "mySwap02's address a:" << &a << endl;
    cout << "mySwap02's address b:" << &b << endl;
...
```

Here,  `a` and `b` are two pointers. They aren't actually `int`s. Now, you're taking the address with `&` of the two **pointers**, not the original integers. This means that you've created two pointers which point to the temporary variables created in `int main()`, and here you're printing the *addresses of the pointers*, not the *addresses of the original variables*.

---

You can fix this in a few ways. You could try to dereference the pointers first, and then take the address of that.

Something like this:

```
void mySwap02(int* a, int* b) {
    cout << "mySwap02's address a:" << &(*a) << endl;
    cout << "mySwap02's address b:" << &(*b) << endl;
...
```

Though, this is obviously redundant; `&` and `*` cancel each other out. So, you could do this:

```
void mySwap02(int* a, int* b) {
    cout << "mySwap02's address a:" << a << endl;
    cout << "mySwap02's address b:" << b << endl;
...
```

Now, the results of `mySwap02` and `mySwap03` are the same.